# Import JSON file from JQuery undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm doing a little script that import the data of JSON file to a JS file with JQuery but when I try to do `console.log(result)` it return undefined. How can I solve it?

JQuery:

```
    document.addEventListener('load',start())
function start() {
    // REQUEST THE DATA FROM API
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'get',
        url: "../api/data.json",
        success: function (result) {
            displayTheData(result)
        }

    });
}

function displayTheData(result) {
    console.log(result)
}
```

JSON:

```
[{
  "name":"Google",
  "url": "google.es",
},
  {
    "name":"Yahoo",
    "url": "yahoo.com",
  }
]
```

Comment: Have you checked whether the .json gets loaded correctly?

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: Are there any errors in the dev tools console?

Comment: no, it just show (undefined) for the console.log

Comment: try this line `console.log(result);` inside success function and see if its still undefined

Comment: it don't work, I changed the location of file and now it shows jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: that means you are calling the function recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is a simple example of your code and its working, its looking like you have some other problem.

```js
function start() {
    // REQUEST THE DATA FROM API
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'get',
        url: "//mysafeinfo.com/api/data",
        data: {list: 'englishmonarchs', format: 'json'},
        }).done(function (result) {
            displayTheData(result)
     });
}

function displayTheData(result) {
    console.log(result)
}

$(function(){
  start();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No, sorry it doesn't it returns undefined

Comment: I put exactly the same I don't understand it

Comment: @Joanmi what version of jQuery you are using?

Comment: I'm using 1.11.1

Comment: @Joanmi I have updated my answer as well try it using the done function

Comment: Now, don't appear nothing on the console, its strange, it is ignoring my console.log

Comment: @Joanmi check the network tab of your devTools while making the request to know if its really loading the json file or not.

Comment: data.json 200 xhr jquery.min.js:4 425 B 7 ms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171750/discussion-between-joanmi-and-muhammad).

Comment: @Joanmi nice to know that, you may check this answer as accepted. :-)